# Pass environment variables to vagrant shell provisioner

Tags: vagrant, environment-variables

It looks like passing environment variables when calling `vagrant up` is simple if you're using a Ruby provisioner:

```
VAR=123 vagrant up
```

In the Vagrantfile:

```
ENV['VAR']
```

How do I do this with the `:shell` provisioner? Simply doing this does not seem to work:

```
$VAR
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

It's not ideal, but I got this to work for now:

```
config.vm.provision "shell" do |s|
    s.inline = "VAR1 is $1 and VAR2 is $2"
    s.args   = "#{ENV['VAR1']} #{ENV['VAR2']}"
end
```

Comment: You may also replace `s.inline` by `s.path` and use the same script you would have passed with `:path => ""`. (My provisioner is hundreds of lines and therefore ill-suited to inlining.)

Comment: Alternatively, using the ruby method with an `:args => ""` parameter, [like so](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461898/passing-variable-to-a-shell-script-provisioner-in-vagrant).

Comment: Should you really have a comma inside `s.args`?

Answer (score 94):

[Since Vagrant 1.8.0](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#180-december-21-2015) you can forget the ugly hacks from the other answers here. Just use the `env` option for the shell provisioner ([docs](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html#env)).

Use it like this in your Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", path: "provisionscript.sh", env: {"MYVAR" => "value"}
```

<sub>This will set the environment for the provisioning script only. If you need a persistent environment variable set for all processes in the VM, this is out of scope for Vagrant provisioning and look here: [Shell environment variables in vagrant files are only passed on first up](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40270391/1254292).</sub>

Comment: In Vagrant 1.8.5, the `env` parameter only seems to work when using a `path` script, not an `inline` script.

Comment: @spyle I'm running Vagrant 1.8.5 (with VirtualBox 5.1.2 on Mac OS X 10.11.6) and `env` works with `inline`.

Comment: Hmm... am I missing something here? This is not working for me:

`config.vm.provision :shell, path: "bootstrap.sh", env: {"MYSQL_DB_USERNAME"=>"django", "MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD"=>"supersecretpasswordwasreplaced"}`

On the other side 

`os.environ['MYSQL_DB_USERNAME']` 

gives a key error :(

Comment: @Tadhg Double check your Vagrant version. And perhaps ask a new question if it doesn't work? It might be an unrelated issue (e.g. Vagrantfile version or environment that isn't preserved in your chain of tools).

Comment: Version is good. You're correct, looking at the doc, it seems that this config is only supposed to work at provisioning time, so I asked this as a new question
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40270391/shell-environment-variables-in-vagrant-files-are-only-passed-on-first-up

Comment: "it seems that this config is only supposed to work at provisioning time" -> yeah, it's a `config.vm.provision` configuration option... and this question is actually about provisioning. :)

Comment: this only explains how you send it but not how you use it.. Can you use it inside `<<-SHELL ... SHELL` ? If not can you combine that with a normal version? For me it only outputs `os.environ['variable']` directly without evaluating it.

I have this: `sudo sed -i -e "s/-Xms.*/os.environ['ELASTIC_XMS']/g" /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options`

Comment: @OZZIE: If you are trying to use it in the Vagrantfile itself, it makes no sense to use *environment* variables. Just use plain variables instead. Environment variables are supposed to be consumed in the process spawned here - the provisioning script. You can access them in any way that's suitable for that scripting language of the script invoked.

Answer (score 20):

For posterity (aka in case I google it again)... It's possible to pass key-value pairs via [env](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html#env):

```
box.vm.provision :shell do |s|
  s.env = {AWS_ACCESS_KEY:ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY'], AWS_SECRET_KEY:ENV['AWS_SECRET_KEY']}
  s.path = 'scripts/bootstrap.sh'
end
```

Then reference them in your script:

```
export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=${AWS_ACCESS_KEY}
export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=${AWS_SECRET_KEY}
```

Bonus feature:

> Vagrant will handle quoting for environment variable values, but the
>   keys remain untouched

Comment: Also see answer posted by @gertvdijk (I didn't have my page refreshed when posting)

Answer (score 16):

I came with this solution for CentOS based provisioning: placing all my required envioronment variables in `/etc/profile.d/vagrant.sh` file and then it's accessed in any provision script.

in short:

```
  $before_script = <<SCRIPT
  echo # vagrant profile script > /etc/profile.d/vagrant.sh
  echo export ENV_VAR1=foo.com/bar >> /etc/profile.d/vagrant.sh
  echo export ENV_VAR2=bar.com/foo >> /etc/profile.d/vagrant.sh
  chmod +x /etc/profile.d/vagrant.sh
SCRIPT

  $after_script = <<SCRIPT
    rm -rf /etc/profile.d/vagrant.sh
SCRIPT

  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $before_script
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "build.sh"
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: $after_script
```

Complete `Vagrantfile` can be found here
https://gist.github.com/bivas/6192d6e422f8ff87c29d

Comment: Works for me under Linux (for an Ubuntu based VM). Awesome!

Comment: Though, there is now https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/provisioning/shell.html#env. I've seen it but due to the lack of examples I skipped it. A colleague pointed out that it works.

Comment: @NikosAlexandris: See my answer :)

Answer (score 8):

You can use `#{ENV['VAR']}` inside an inline script, e.g.:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-END
  ...
  # Install my dotfiles are there.  If you're in a hurry you can do
  # SKIP_DOTFILES=1 vagrant up
  if ! [ -d /home/vagrant/dotfiles ] && [ -z '#{ENV['SKIP_DOTFILES']}']; then
    if ! [ -x /usr/bin/git ]; then
      DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y git
    fi
    su - vagrant -c 'git clone https://github.com/mgedmin/dotfiles'
    su - vagrant -c 'dotfiles/install.sh'
  fi
  ...
  END
```

Example taken from a working Vagrantfile.

This has some disadvantages: if $VAR contains single quotes, things will break.

Comment: Of course I notice that @Bob essentially provided the same answer (in the NEW WAY bit) *right after* I post mine.  Augh!

Answer (score 7):

Incase someone ends up looking for how to set variables in the provisioning script's environment, this worked for me.

```
config.vm.provision :shell, :inline => <<-SH
  export GRAPHITE_HOST=192.168.33.10
  /vagrant/install_app_with_monitoring.sh
SH
```

Note that this assumes you're sharing your working directory as `/vagrant` on the VM but this should be the default.

Comment: but why not do this inside `install_app_with_monitoring.sh`?

Comment: Mainly to keep knowledge in the same place. You can see an example here https://github.com/forty9ten/monitoring-with-graphite/blob/master/Vagrantfile#L8-L29

By keeping the var in the Vagrantfile it's easy to ensure parity between `private_network` and `GRAPHITE_HOST`.

Could even take it a step further and use `export GRAPHITE_HOST=#{ip}` to reference a single common ruby var.

Answer (score 6):

Most of these answers seems to be outdated. With Vagrant 2.1.1 this worked for me:

```
  VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2" //...

  machine.vm.provision "shell", 
    env: {
      "ELASTIC_XMS" => servers["elastic"]["memory_xms"], 
      "ELASTIC_XMX" => servers["elastic"]["memory_xmx"]
    }, 
    inline: "sed -i -e \"s/-Xms.*/$ELASTIC_XMS/g\" /etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options"
```

Answer (score 2):

The [vagrant-env](https://github.com/gosuri/vagrant-env) plugin does exactly this. With it, you can add environment variables to `.env` file in the local directory which will be loaded in `Vagrant` file. I suggest to keep `.env` in your `.gitignore`, this way you have your privacy guaranteed.

Comment: Plugin died back in 2015, this isn't current.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I have it working.

I went from using the vagrant puppet provisioner way to just using the shell provisioner.  I did this mainly because I wanted to puppet not to run as root, shell provider gives you :privileged => false.

MY OLD WAY:

```
config.vm.provision :puppet do |puppet|
  puppet.module_path = ENV.fetch('MODULES_PATH', 'modules')
  puppet.manifests_path = ENV.fetch('MANIFESTS_PATH', 'manifests')
  puppet.manifest_file  = ENV.fetch('MANIFEST_FILE', 'site.pp')
  puppet.options = "--debug"
end
```

MY NEW WAY:

```
config.vm.provision :shell, :privileged => false do |shell|
  shell.inline = "puppet apply --debug --modulepath '/vagrant/#{ENV.fetch('MODULES_PATH', 'modules')}' --detailed-exitcodes '/vagrant/#{ENV.fetch('MANIFESTS_PATH', 'manifests')}/#{ENV.fetch('MANIFEST_FILE', 'site.pp')}'"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify for `shell` using `inline`in your `Vagrantfile` file:

```
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: %Q(/usr/bin/env FOO=1 BAR=1 bash /path/to/script.sh)
```

Or load some extra variables from YAML file:

```
require 'yaml'
dir = File.dirname(File.expand_path(__FILE__))
vconfig = YAML::load_file("#{dir}/config.yml")
config.vm.provision "shell", inline: %Q(/usr/bin/env FOO=#{vconfig['foo']} bash /path/to/script.sh)
```

Alternatively you may implement some optional arguments from the command line, e.g.:

```
# Parse optional arguments.
opts = GetoptLong.new(
  [ '--foo',  GetoptLong::OPTIONAL_ARGUMENT ], # With optional parameter.
  [ '--bar',  GetoptLong::OPTIONAL_ARGUMENT ], # With optional parameter.files.
)
opts.each do |opt, arg|
  case opt
    when '--foo'
      foo==arg
    when '--bar'
      bar=arg
  end
end
```

then use: `opt['--foo'].to_s`.

See also: [How to pass parameter on Vagrant up and have it in the scope of Chef cookbook?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14124234/55075)

Answer (score -3):

this worked for me

```
VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION = "2"

kettle_dir = ENV['KETTLE_DIR']
Vagrant.configure(VAGRANTFILE_API_VERSION) do |config|
   config.vm.synced_folder kettle_dir, "/pentaho"
   config.vm.box = "ubuntu/trusty64"
end
```

Comment: Can you put in some detail to indicate why this is the correct answer?

Comment: This uses an environment variable in the Vagrantfile, but doesn't actually set one for the provisioner as asked in the question.

Answer (score -3):

On a ubutnu box I simply did the following in my bootstrap.sh:

```
echo "DBHOST=localhost" >> /etc/environment
echo "DBNAME=foo" >> /etc/environment
echo "DBUSER=root" >> /etc/environment
echo "DBPASSWD=root" >> /etc/environment
```