# Pass Environment Variable into Vagrant instance

Tags: linux, windows, environment-variables, vagrant

I have a Windows host with some environment variables. I would like to be able to pass them into a Vagrant linux instance to write into a file.

This works for simple values of %foo%.

```
vagrant ssh -c "echo %foo% | tee -a /tmp/file"
```

However, if %foo% has a $ in it, it messes up because linux interprets it as a variable.

Is there a way I can automagically escape any $ symbols in %foo% or get linux to not interpret it?

I had found this SO question, but it runs into the same $ problem: [Pass environment variables to vagrant shell provisioner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648088/pass-environment-variables-to-vagrant-shell-provisioner)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply quote it with single quotes:

```
vagrant ssh -c "echo '%foo%' | tee -a /tmp/file"
```

I just hope `%foo%` doesn't expand to something that has single quotes as well.