# Ubuntu - Python - Get Windows username session

Tags: python, windows, session, virtual-machine, virtualbox

My computer's operating system is Windows. I use "my_lastname.myfirst_name" login to access to my windows user session.
For my new Django python project, I'm using ubuntu OS in a virtual machine.
I'm trying to get my login windows from the virtual machine.
To do this i used these examples:

```
>> import pwd
>> user_name = pwd.getpwuid( os.getuid() )[ 0 ]
```

---

```
>> import socket
>> user_name = socket.gethostname()
```

The above blocs of code give me the localhost name of the ubuntu machine.

How can i access to windows session username from the ubuntu guest OS with python ?

Comment: Are you using VirtualBox? Vagrant? Docker?

Comment: yes,  i'm using VirtualBox and Vagrant

Comment: Don't have time to write a full answer, but you should look into setting the environment variable through the Vagrant file http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19648088/pass-environment-variables-to-vagrant-shell-provisioner. If that doesn't work, you could set it through VirtualBox https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=73154.