# Pass command line argument to vagrant shell script provisioner

Tags: ruby, shell, vagrant, provisioning

Similar to this question: [Passing variable to a shell script provisioner in vagrant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461898/passing-variable-to-a-shell-script-provisioner-in-vagrant)

I want to pass variables to a shell script provisioner but I want to set these variables on the command line when I call the provisioner. Is this possible?

Comment: so you want to do something like `vagrant up arg1 arg2` and send arg1 and arg2 to the provisioner ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is what I would try - I guess there are possibilities as Vagrantfile is a ruby script, you can use most of ruby possibilities

Be careful though as vagrant might need to check for variables, for example when doing `vagrant up arg1 arg2`, it expects arg1 and arg2 to be machine names defined in Vagrantfile and will raise an error as it cannot find it

So you would need to pass those variables like

```
vagrant --arg1 --arg2 up
```

To read them you could

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

v1 = ARGV[0]
v2 = ARGV[1]
array_arg = [v1, v2]


Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  blabla config

  array_arg.each do |arg|
    config.vm.provision "shell", run: "always" do |s|
      s.inline = "echo $1"
      s.args   = arg
    end
  end
end
```

for example, the execution would give

```
fhenri@machine:~/project$ vagrant --arg1 --arg2 up
    . . . . . 
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: --arg1
==> default: Running provisioner: shell...
    default: Running: inline script
==> default: stdin: is not a tty
==> default: --arg2
```

Comment: I'd like to call `vagrant provision --arg1` such that it doesn't run `vagrant up` but rather `vagrant provision` (in case the machine is up but needs reprovisioning)

Comment: if you want to have your own variable you should have then right after `vagrant` command, if you put it after the vagrant command like the provision command, vagrant would expect its a parameter for its own command and will claim there's an error. If you run `vagrant --arg1 provision` in this case it will still run the provision only

Answer (score 0):

In your Vagrantfile, add the following  -

```
{
    "PROVISION_PARAMS" => "some_default_values",
}.each { |key, value| ENV[key] = value if ENV[key] == nil }
```

These arguments can now be passed to shell script provisioner in the following way -

```
config.vm.provision :shell, privileged: true, run: "always",
                            :path => "../../scripts/script.ps1", 
                            :args => ENV['PROVISION_PARAMS']
```

You can now provide command line arguments to this script in the following manner -

```
$ PROVISION_PARAMS=' param1 param2 "param 3" ' vagrant provision
```

And the script will take default values if these parameters are not specified.