# How to use Vagrant-proxyconf in multiple environments

Tags: proxy, vagrant, vagrant-windows

At work I am behind a proxy server and have configured vagrant to use it through the vagrant-proxyconf plugin. It works great and no problems or complaints there.

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-proxyconf")
    config.proxy.http      = "http://proxy.server.com:8080"
    config.proxy.https     = "http://proxy.server.com:8080"
    config.proxy.no_proxy  = "localhost, 127.0.0.1"
  else
    raise Vagrant::Errors::VagrantError.new, "Plugin missing: vagrant-proxyconf"
  end
```

The problem that I'm having is when I take my computer home to do some work. Is there a way to easily turn off the proxy settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off proxy by adding

```
config.proxy.enabled = false
```

to your Vagrantfile but you need to edit the file to make the change (true/false flag). you can also use external config file if you already have but it still requires a file edit

what I would try based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33070700/pass-command-line-argument-to-vagrant-shell-script-provisioner/33084236#33084236) is something like

```
vagrant true/false up
```

and in your Vagrantfile

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

proxy_val = ARGV[0]

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-proxyconf")
    config.proxy.enabled   = proxy_val
    config.proxy.http      = "http://proxy.server.com:8080"
    config.proxy.https     = "http://proxy.server.com:8080"
    config.proxy.no_proxy  = "localhost, 127.0.0.1"
  else
    raise Vagrant::Errors::VagrantError.new, "Plugin missing: vagrant-proxyconf"
  end
```

If you have some ruby skills you can even come up with something nicer but this gives you an idea

*Note* turns out even if proxy is disabled, the proxy value are still set as mentioned from the [doc](https://github.com/tmatilai/vagrant-proxyconf/)

> This disabling keeps proxy configurations for applications on the
>   guest. The configurations must be cleared before disabling if needed.

so another possibility using the above proposal is to do something like

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

proxy_val = ARGV[0]

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  if Vagrant.has_plugin?("vagrant-proxyconf")
    config.proxy.enabled   = proxy_val
    if (proxy_val) 
      config.proxy.http      = "http://proxy.server.com:8080"
      config.proxy.https     = "http://proxy.server.com:8080"
      config.proxy.no_proxy  = "localhost, 127.0.0.1"
    else
      config.proxy.http      = ""
      config.proxy.https     = ""
      config.proxy.no_proxy  = ""
  else
    raise Vagrant::Errors::VagrantError.new, "Plugin missing: vagrant-proxyconf"
  end
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try it in a bit. I have one other question for you if you have the time.

If I configured the network in the vagrant file to be a public network, shouldn't that piggyback off of my host machine's connection?

(config.vm.network "public_network")

I tried this and it doesn't work so I think I might be misunderstanding something.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion and found that it's half way there.

proxy.enable enables/disables the plugin, but it doesn't overwrite the proxy values that it sets. What I had to do instead was pass an argument into the shell script provisioner like you suggested, and then based on if that was true of false, set the proxies (config.proxy.http="http://proxy.server.com:8080") or unset them (config.proxy.http = ""). If you edit your answer you'll mark it accepted.

Comment: Thanks Dan, I edited accordingly - back to the additional question, I am not quite sure to understand what you mean - you should be able to access your VM from any machine on the same network, there are already questions on SO on this topic if thats what you mean