# Scale vagrant box horizontally

Tags: vagrant

Lets say I have a box defined in vagrant, what would be the way to scale that box horizontally? The thing I have in mind is Azure VM Scale Set, where you just tell it to add a VM and it adds another VM just like the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vagrant does not have this possibility - It creates a VM, if you want to 'scale' you need to create a 2nd machine from your Vagranfile

Vagrantfile is a ruby script .. you can put this number as arguments to command line (check https://stackoverflow.com/a/33084236/4296747) and then pass that in a loop to create multiple VMs

If you use docker, docker-compose has a nice [scale option](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/scale/) but its not there yet for Vagrant

Comment: so, i would need a script that would go and do vagrant up a bunch of times, each in a new dir? or something like that, and probably alter the vagrantfile a bit?

Comment: 1 Vagrantfile can manage multiple VM - as Vagrantfile is a ruby script you can create loop to create multiple VM. vagrant up can start all or you can name which VM to startup. check [vagrant multiple machine](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/multi-machine/) and you will find tons of example on internet

Comment: if all your VM are provisioning the same way, you will boot multiple machines with same config (different IP though) - as I said an easy scale option is not available in vagrant, you need to do it yourself in the Vagrantfile

Comment: Vagrantfile is a ruby script .. you can put this number as arguments to command line (check http://stackoverflow.com/a/33084236/4296747) and then pass that in a loop to create multiple VMs